# Is there a way to have a php variable in a javascript dynamically created html input?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

so i have a record that has a one-to-many relationship with another named outcome which each has atleast one person to make a team.

For the team, i am dynamically creating the fields to a maximum of 9 people in each. not to confuse which outcome each person in the team belongs to, i am passing the outcome id.

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn add_field_button">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add More Fields
</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var new_fields      = 19;
    var i = $("")

    var x = 1; //initial text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            new_fields++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="row"><input type="text" name="outcome[' +new_fields +'][' +x +'][id]" value="<?php echo $outcome->id; ?>" class="form-control" hidden><div class="form-group col-lg-4"><label class="form-control-label text-muted ">*Officer\'s Name:</label><input type="text" name="outcome[' +new_fields +'][' +x +'][officer]" class="form-control" required></div><div class="col-lg-4 form-group-sub"><label class="form-control-label text-muted">*Position:</label><input type="text" name="outcome[' +new_fields +'][' +x +'][position]" class="form-control" required></div><div class="col-lg-3 form-group-sub"><label class="form-control-label text-muted">*Institution Name:</label><select class="form-control" id="institution" name="outcome[' +new_fields +'][' +x +'][institution]" required><option value="">Select Institution</option><option value="option1">First Option</option><option value="option2">Second Option</option><option value="other">Other</option></select></div><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>');
      //add input box
        }
    });
```

I have tried double curly brackets for the variables but it isn't working.

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
{"2":{"id":"<?php echo $outcome->id; ?>","officer":"Munthu Oyamba","position":"Ofunika heve","institution":"option1"}},"21":{"3":{"id":"<?php echo $outcome->id; ?>","officer":"Munthu Wachiwiri","position":"Bwantasa","institution":"option2"}}}
```

Comment: Is this a `.js` file or a `<script>` inside of a `.blade.php` file? Cause PHP syntax will only work in one of those.

Comment: This helped! it was in a .js file but i moved it to <script> and it is working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Excellent :) Yeah, a common misconception for Laravel developers is the expectation that `.blade.php` syntax (like `{{ }}`, etc) is available everywhere, including `.js` files. Once you realize what's going on, it's pretty clear the issue, and thankfully the solution too. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the javascript in your Blade template, this should work as it is injecting the string (value of my_var) in to the JS block:

```
$my_var = 'hi mom!';

<script>
   console.log( {{ $my_var }} );
</script>
```

If your php variable has markup to be rendered you can use `{!! $my_var !!}`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code is executed in your browser. Your browser does not know how to execute php code.
The php code needs to be executed server side, which means before the page is even sent to your browser. Dynamically adding `<?php ?>` tags to your page does nothing.